# Jekyll server address is //

Tags: jekyll, bundle

When running `bundle exec jekyll serve`, I get the following: `Server address: http://0.0.0.0:4000//`

Where does `//` come from in my config? How do I get rid of it to get `http://0.0.0.0:4000/` ?

**`_config.yaml`**

```
url:         https://blabla.com
source:      .
destination: ./_site
plugins_dir:     ./_plugins
layouts_dir:     ./_layouts
include:     ['.htaccess']
exclude:     []
timezone:    UTC+1
plugins: [jekyll-paginate]

# Show future posts
future:      true
show_drafts: nil
limit_posts: 500
highlighter: rouge

relative_permalinks: false

permalink:     pretty
paginate_path: 'posts/:num'
paginate: 5

markdown:      kramdown
markdown_ext:  kramdown, markdown,mkd,mkdn,md
textile_ext:   textile
kramdown:
  input: GFM
  syntax_highlighter: rouge
excerpt_separator: "<!-- more -->"

safe:        false
host:        0.0.0.0
port:        4000
baseurl:     /
lsi:         false

rdiscount:
  extensions: []

redcarpet:
  extensions: []

kramdown:
  auto_ids: true
  footnote_nr: 1
  entity_output: as_char
  toc_levels: 1..6
  smart_quotes: lsquo,rsquo,ldquo,rdquo
  enable_coderay: false
  input: GFM

syntax_highlighter_opts:
  coderay:
    coderay_wrap: div
    coderay_line_numbers: inline
    coderay_line_numbers_start: 1
    coderay_tab_width: 4
    coderay_bold_every: 10
    coderay_css: style

redcloth:
  hard_breaks: true

#
# jekyll-assets: see more at https://github.com/ixti/jekyll-assets
# bundle exec jekyll serve
#
assets:

  dirname: assets
  baseurl: /assets/
  sources:
    - _assets/javascripts
    - _assets/stylesheets
    - _assets/images
    - _assets/fonts
  js_compressor: uglifier
  css_compressor: sass
  cachebust: none
  cache: true
  gzip: [ text/css, application/javascript ]
  debug: true
  compressors:
    uglifier:
      harmony: true
      compress:
        unused: false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jekyll default config : `baseurl: "" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog`

Your `baseurl` must be empty.